# Can Docker be used to run Linux CLI tools from macOS?

Tags: linux, docker

I am writing software on macOS.  As a subroutine I would like to call certain Linux-only CLI tools, e.g., `> mytool inputfile`.  Can I use Docker for Mac to compile the Linux tool inside a container and call it from outside the container (after copying input files into the container?).  And if I can, is it a good idea or will there be issues installing and compiling Linux packages?

From my understanding of docker as basically a lightweight VM that uses a stripped down version of a Linux distribution, this approach seems to make sense, but the stripped down aspect might be an impediment.

Comment: Yes you can, it's indeed a lightweight VM and you can run different base images (aka OS / environments)

Comment: "Is it a good idea or will there be issues installing and compiling Linux packages" -- it highly depends on what you compile and install

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov thanks for your comments, I realize that without the specific tool this question is somewhat generic, but as an academic researcher I often run into issues with different Linux only tools, that's why I wanted to get an idea of the general suitability of this approach.

Comment: MacOS is actually a different flavor of Unix (based on BSD rather than Linux and the GNU user space); can you rebuild the application to run natively on MacOS?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'd say rebuilding the application is definitely the best solution when possible -- and luckily some researchers provide clear instructions for this, however, for many of the tools I encounter this is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

> Can Docker be used to run Linux CLI tools from macOS?

Docker supports macOS according to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/).

> Can I use Docker for Mac to compile the Linux tool inside a container and call it from outside the container (after copying input files into the container?

Yes.

> And if I can, is it a good idea

Depends on the term "good" - it's subjective and highly depends on specific case.

> or will there be issues installing and compiling Linux packages?

No.

> From my understanding of docker as basically a lightweight VM

Yes.

> that uses a stripped down version of a Linux distribution, this approach seems to make sense, but the stripped down aspect might be an impediment.

What is in docker container depends on the container. Overall, usually man pages and system package manager repository information are removed from images. I would disagree - mostly docker containers come with full Linux distributions and can be used as such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KamilCuk, as I mentioned in a comment I realize that its hard to answer suitability without a specific case, but I would be interested in applying this solution to several cases.  What factors would render this approach impractical?  I can imagine frequent calls to the command inside docker being an issue, for example.

Comment: `What factors would render this approach impractical?` None. `I can imagine frequent calls to the command inside docker being an issue` I cannot, you would just call it frequently. The limit is in resources - CPU, ram and disc space. Anyway, for "impractical" you would firstly define what is "practical". Surely there might be problems for short interactive programs like `ls`, because _the user_ will get frustrated when you will have to wait a sec till it shows the output. But then you could buy a faster pc.

Comment: Meh `alias ls='docker run -ti --rm -v $PWD:/data --workdir /data alpine ls'` works fine here I hardly even notice a delay. Power of SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this gives a very clear idea of what the drawbacks are in this case (i.e., none that can't be solved without some extra hardware).

Answer (score 1):

You should do as follow:

```sh
docker run --rm -v /:/host -ti ubuntu ... your command referring to /host...
```

And this is the command parameters explanation:

1. `--rm` : remove sthe container after running (but keep cached the image for next calls).
2. `-t` : allocates a visibile shell terminal.
3. `-i` : runs in interactive mode.
4. `-v /:/host` : maps your **root folder** to container `/host` folder.
5. `ubuntu` : pulls the **ubuntu** image, which you can change with any other you prefer.
6. As last parameter put the commands to run into the container but relatives to `/host`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, do I understand correctly though that this command builds the image and runs the `mytool` command at once?  If I need to first apt get some packages and compile `mytool`, this should be done up front to create a suitable image first?

Comment: Sure, you can build a your own (customized) image in place of the ubuntu provided as example.